# Typescript. Настройка файла tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript

Подскажите, что написать в файле tsconfig.json, чтобы перенаправлять компиляцию js файлов в нужную папку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас есть параметр outDir: "path"
У вас будет файл выглядеть как то так:

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
   "target": "es5",
   ....
   "outDir": "dist"
 }
}
```